# How to make chapter numbers in TOC as non-link (hyperref package)

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents, numbering

I'm using the hyperref package to enable PDF links & bookmarks in the output file. I would like to achieve the following behavior (`[]` denotes clickable area}

```
1 [The first chapter] .............. 3
2 [The second chapter] ............. 8
```

When using the `linktoc=section` option in hyperref, I can achieve this:

```
[1 The first chapter] .............. 3
[2 The second chapter] ............. 8
```

Which is not really what I wanted.

Anyone aware of a solution?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to have any greeting.

Comment: @lockstep: Hello :) thanks for such a warm welcoming! Indeed, I am new to the TeX part of stackexchange. I didn't realise that a "Hi," at the beginning was an offense against the tex.sx rules.

Comment: Somewhat related question: [How to make a hyperlink cover the whole line in table of contents including the dots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28806/3323)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following patch should work:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\process@contentsline#1#2{#1#2\hyper@linkstart{link}{\toc@link@target}\bgroup}
\patchcmd{\contentsline}{\hyper@linkstart{link}{#4}{#2}\hyper@linkend}{\def\toc@link@target{#4}\process@contentsline#2\egroup\hyper@linkend}{}{}
\patchcmd{\contentsline}{\hyper@linkstart{link}{#4}{#2}\hyper@linkend}{\def\toc@link@target{#4}\process@contentsline#2\egroup\hyper@linkend}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Insert this code after having loaded the `hyperref` package. It patches `hyperref`'s version of the `contentsline` macro (two times, as the part to be replaced occurs twice):

Instead of calling the `\hyper@linkstart` command which creates the clickable link directly, the newly created `\process@contentsline` macro is called. It outputs its two arguments directly, without a link - these create the section number. Afterwards, it starts the link which will contain the rest of the text of the contents line.

[image]