# restricting hyperref link to part of toc / lo* entry

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft

In some *tocloft* list there are entries, which may span multiple lines. Now *hyperref* makes the number in front, the first line and all the following lines into links. Can this be prevented? Only the first line should be a link.
See the following example, where this happens:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listprname}{Problems}
\newlistof{pr}{pr}{\listprname}

\newcommand\pr[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{pr}
    \addcontentsline{pr}{pr}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thepr.}{#1\\#2}}}

\begin{document}

    \listofpr

    \pr{Test}{This is rather a description.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Mico's answer and the other article, [How to make a hyperlink cover the whole line in table of contents including the dots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-cover-the-whole-line-in-table-of-contents-including-the), I figured it out:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listprname}{Problems}
\newlistof{pr}{pr}{\listprname}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\pr[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{pr}
    \addcontentsline{pr}{pr}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thepr.}{\protect\hyper@linkstart{link}{pr.\thepr}#1\protect\hyper@linkend\\#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \listofpr

    \pr{Test}{This is rather a description.}

\end{document}
```

Of course this relies on the internal label naming scheme of *hyperref*. Also the number in front is not a link for now, but that can be added too.

Furthermore settings can be changed for each list separately by using `\hypersetup{linktoc=page}` before and `\hypersetup{linktoc=all}` after the list, the changes shall be applied to. This way no changes are necessary to keep the entries in the main toc as links.

---

As Heiko noted, it is not necessary to use the internal `hyperref` commands. The following code contains this adjustment and also puts the number in a link:

```
\addcontentsline{pr}{pr}%
{\protect\numberline{\protect\hyperlink{pr.\thepr}{\thepr.}}%
    {\protect\hyperlink{pr.\thepr}{#1}\\#2}}%
```

Comment: You get the number into the link by putting `\numberline`with its number argument in the link. Also there is no need for internal commands. Result: `{\protect\hyperlink{pr.\thepr}{\protect\numberline{\thepr.}#1\\#2}}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: If you do that, you are missing the point of the question: only the first line should be in the hyperlink. But nevertheless you are correct about the use of internal commands. I will add that to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: It was just a typing error: `{\protect\hyperlink{pr.\thepr}{\protect\numberline{\thepr.}#1}\\#2}` (comments do not seem to allow properly formatted and indented code).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: That makes sense of course and I stick with seperate `\hyperlink`s only, because then it is a little bit easier to handle empty first/second line.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of an option of the hyperref package that achieves your stated goal. However, you may want to consider specifying the `linktocpage=true` option, which will make the page numbers associated with the entries in the TOC, LoF, and LoT into hyperlink targets. Personally, I find the option to "color" just the page numbers, rather than all other parts of a given entry in these lists, quite appealing.