# Hyperref links entire line (like Word)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft

I have tried to use the code from [How to make a hyperlink cover the whole line in table of contents including the dots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-cover-the-whole-line-in-table-of-contents-including-the) but it seems to make my entire document *hyperlinked* probably due to my custom style. I am using the `tocloft` package. I was wondering if I could have the entire line *hyperlinked* like

```
[1 Introduction ...... 1]
```

Where everything in between `[]` is linked

I can only seem to get either the title, the number, or both, but not the entire line.

---

Here is my MWE. I included all the current packages I will be using in case there's a conflict between some of them.

```
\documentclass{ut-thesis}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\degree{Masters}
\department{Deparment}
\gradyear{2013}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Thesis Title}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%%%      MAIN  DOCUMENT      %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{preliminary}

        \maketitle

        \begin{abstract}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
            This is my abstract!
        \end{abstract}

        %Add Figure into the list of figures and tables
        \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure\ }
        \renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table\ }
        \newlength{\mylenf}
        \settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
        \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+1.5em}
        \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+1.5em}

        \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents

        \listoffigures
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

        \listoftables
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

    \end{preliminary}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Motivation}

    This is a section

    \printbibliography
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

It seems that the problems are coming from

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents`
```

And obviously if I delete it I can't see if it's working since I no longer print the table of contents.

---

EDIT

I've made no progress and I would still like some help if possible.

Comment: Can you post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?  If something in that custom style is messing things over, we won't be able to tell until we see it :)

Answer (score 3):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) generates and transfers the hyperlinks *verbatim* to whichever package you use for setting your ToC. This allows `hyperref` to be compatible with a host of packages. Since it's known that you're using the combination

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
```

we can knowing update what `hyperref` transfers and update the way [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) sets the ToC entries.

Let's look at how ToC-related entries are processed under `hyperref` by looking at a generic ToC entry:

```
\contentsline {<type>}{<title>}{<page>}{<hyperlink>}
```

`hyperref` translates `\contentsline{<type>}` to be equivalent to `\csname l@<type>\endcsname` (or `\l@<type>`). Additionally, it inserts a hyperlink *start* and *end* group around both `<title>` and `<page>` using the `<hyperlink>` marker. Effectively, using HTML-link tags, the above is translated into

```
<a href="<hyperlink>"><title></a> . . . <a href="<hyperlink>"><page></a>
```

You want to change the above to

```
<a href="<hyperlink>"><title> . . . <page></a>
```

so we need to intervene *before* `hyperref` passes the hyperlinks to `tocloft`, otherwise it isn't possible to combine the two separate `<title>` and `<page>` hyperlinks into one. Here are the steps:

1. Remove the insertion of hyperlinks performed by `hyperref`. Since we know you're using the `linktoc=all` option, an override of `\contentsline` that resembles the following suffices:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
     \begingroup
       \Hy@safe@activestrue
     \edef\x{\endgroup
       \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
     }\x
     % ...removed a bunch of conditionals knowing you're using 'linktoc=all'
     \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
       %\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
       #2%
     }{%
       %\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
       #3%
     }%
   }
   \makeatother
   ```

   You'll note that the hyperlink *start* and *end* surrounding `#2` and `#3` respectively have been removed, and we just pass `#2` and `#3` as-is to `tocloft`.
2. Manually insert the removed contents above as part of `tocloft`s formatting for chapters and sections (additional levels can be added, but since you're using `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` I didn't add these):

   ```
   \makeatletter
   % Update ToC hyperlinks for Chapters
   \patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
     {{\cftchapfont #1}}% <search>
     {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{}{\cftchapfont #1}}% <replace>
     {}{}% <success><failure>
   \patchcmd{\cftchapfillnum}{\par}{\hyper@linkend\par}{}{}
   % Update ToC hyperlinks for Sections
   \patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
     {{\cftsecfont #1}}% <search>
     {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{}{\cftsecfont #1}}% <replace>
     {}{}% <success><failure>
   \patchcmd{\cftsecfillnum}{\par}{\hyper@linkend\par}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

   Each ToC-related entry has two [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patches associated with it. The first inserts the hyperlink *start*, while the second inserts the hyperlink *end* before there is a `\par`agraph break (hyperlinks can't be inserted in vertical mode).

Here is a complete minimal example showing your setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ut-thesis}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\degree{Masters}
\department{Deparment}
\gradyear{2013}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Thesis Title}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
  }\x
  \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
    %\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
    #2%
  }{%
    %\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
    #3%
  }%
}
% Update ToC hyperlinks for Chapters
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
  {{\cftchapfont #1}}% <search>
  {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{}{\cftchapfont #1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\cftchapfillnum}{\par}{\hyper@linkend\par}{}{}
% Update ToC hyperlinks for Sections
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {{\cftsecfont #1}}% <search>
  {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{}{\cftsecfont #1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\cftsecfillnum}{\par}{\hyper@linkend\par}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{preliminary}

  \maketitle

  \begin{abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    This is my abstract!
  \end{abstract}

  %Add Figure into the list of figures and tables
  \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure\ }
  \renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table\ }
  \newlength{\mylenf}
  \settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
  \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+1.5em}
  \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+1.5em}

  \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents

  \listoffigures
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

  \listoftables
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\end{preliminary}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}

This is a section

\section{This is a very long section title 
         this is a very long section title 
         this is a very long section title
         this is a very long section title}

\end{document}
```

Hyperlinks spanning multiple lines are not formatted well, but that's just the way it is. I'd suggest using

```
\<type>[<ToC title>]{<main title>}
```

instead to format a `<ToC title>` that better fits the ToC width.

Comment: Very thorough, and nicely explained!