# Modifying \@dottedtocline to include a hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, documentclass-writing

I am trying to edit the \@dottedtocline command to give a hyperlink on the dots as well as the chapter title and the page number. I searched for this and found exactly what I want [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-cover-the-whole-line-in-table-of-contents-including-the), unfortunately I am forced to use a custom document class for this file, and as a result the solution doesn't work. I have managed to find the exact renew command that is causing the problem, but I don't know the syntax of the commands to fix it myself, so any help would be appreciated. To be clear, I have access to, and can make (minor) edits to, the document class file.

Here is the code in the cls file that is causing the problem:

```
\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
%%   Handling those sections that are included in TOC, but have
%%   no section numbering. Also including hanging indent when the
%%   NoTocHang option was not used. Only the following 4 lines added.
     \ifthenelse{#1 > \value{secnumdepth}}{%
     \setlength{\@tempdima}{0pt}}{}%
    % \ifthenelse{#1 > \value{secnumdepth} \or \boolean{RS@TOCHang}}{%
    % \addtolength{\leftskip}{\RS@TOChdent}}{}%
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaddots
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

Here is the proposed fix (the code by itself compiles fine, but with the custom cls it doesn't fix my problem anymore).

```
    \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\contentsline}
  {\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}
     {\leaders}
     {\hyper@linkstart{link}{#4}\leaders}
     {}
     {}%
   \patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}
     {\hfill}
     {\hfill\hyper@linkend}
     {}
     {}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter} \pagebreak
\section{First Section} \pagebreak
\subsection{First Subsection}
\chapter{Second Chapter} \pagebreak
\section{Second Section} \pagebreak
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to compile a duplicate of the above code, but using the cls doc type. The above code (the suggested fix code) on it's own does exactly what it's suppose to (it works). With the CLS file type, it compiles fine, but the result acts as if the above patch isn't there (same results with it commented out or not).
I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that uses the custom `.cls` `\@dottedtocline` so that it replicates the problem? If I copy `\@dottedtocline` into your example together with the patch I can't replicate what you're saying... In essence, we need to copy-and-paste-and-compile a block of code and see exactly what your problem is.

Comment: I actually found the cls file available online, with the above statement you should be able to exactly replicate the whole thing as needed. The cls file is here: http://pastebin.com/T9kT6bHS. I also made more headway and posted the results to a reddit thread in an effort to get more help since this place went a bit dark.. so better info is available here: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/3niqu1/little_help_with_hyperlink_syntax_code_included/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following achieves what  you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ufthesis}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
%%   Handling those sections that are included in TOC, but have
%%   no section numbering. Also including hanging indent when the
%%   NoTocHang option was not used. Only the following 4 lines added.
     \ifthenelse{#1 > \value{secnumdepth}}{%
     \setlength{\@tempdima}{0pt}}{}%
    % \ifthenelse{#1 > \value{secnumdepth} \or \boolean{RS@TOCHang}}{%
    % \addtolength{\leftskip}{\RS@TOChdent}}{}%
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#4}\nobreak% <-- hyperlink start
     \leaddots
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \hyper@linkend% <-- hyperlink end
     \par}%
  \fi}

\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
  }\x
  \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifcase\Hy@linktoc % none
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
    \or % section
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
      }{#3}%
    \or % page
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{{#2}}{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \else % all
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        }{}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          #2%\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        }{%
          #3%\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter} \pagebreak
\section{First Section} \pagebreak
\subsection{First Subsection}
\chapter{Second Chapter} \pagebreak
\section{Second Section} \pagebreak
\subsection{Second Subsection}

\end{document}
```

The above code updates `\@dottedtocline` from [the `ufthesis` class](http://www.ufthesis.ece.ufl.edu/) and `\contentsline` from [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). It removes any hyperlinking insertions from the latter, and places them as part of the former. This way the hyperlink stretches across the ToC-entry title to the page number (including the leader dots).

Comment: You Sir (or Ma'am) are remarkably helpful. It seems like you hunt my questions down and give me exactly what I need, I can't thank you enough. This works perfectly as is.
On a related note, I tried to figure out how to do a bunch of this myself without a lot of success because I couldn't find any decent primer on how the hyperlinking primitives work. Do you happen to have a decent reference? (Or general references to the primitives would be all around outstanding)

Comment: @Jason: It comes from years of tinkering and identifying the source code that is associated with commands. In this case, specifically, I looked at the source code of [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to see how the hyperlinks are inserted (`\hyper@linkstart{link}{destination}`...`\hyper@linkend`) and then transferred that detail to before the sectional unit entry up to the ending of the page number... this was done inside `\@dottedtocline`...

Comment: @Jason: ...It also required removal of the link insertions inside `\contentsline`, and since `\contentsline` was intricate, it was easier to copy everything from the source definition inside [`hyperref.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.dtx) and cut out the bits I wanted removed.