# KOMA-script/hyperref: Make page number and section number (and nothing else) into hyperlinks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, koma-script

I am using KOMA-script with hyperref and have set up my table of contents with  `tocbasic`.

I would like to format my TOC in the way presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574842/change-hyperlinks-in-table-of-contents-to-section-number-and-page-number-only),
that is, to have the page number *and* the entry number made into hyperlinks, *and nothing else*.

This is the desired result (`[]` denotes hyperlinks):

```
[I] Foo ......... [3]
[1] Bar ......... [5]
[1.1] Baz ....... [5]
```

However, Ulrike Fischer's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575191) there works perfectly for classes `article` and `book`, but it fails as soon as it's changed to `scrartcl` or `scrbook`. Possibly because in KOMA-script, a different command is in charge of the entry number than in the standard classes.

I have also tried to replicate the approach of [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28926/) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16659/)
related answers –
i.e. patch `\contentsline` using `etoolbox`, adding `\hyper@linkstart{link}{<some #>}` and `\hyper@linkend` around the entry number.

But I'm hitting the same wall: those answers work for the standard classes but do not (seem to) translate to KOMA-Script/tocbasic.

Is anyone able to help?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[linktoc=page,           % plus, if possible, the entry number
colorlinks]{hyperref}           

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{Baz}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

@esdd has provided two great solutions.

It is worth pointing out **a difference in their usage.**

The second one uses hooks from `tocbasic` that are, as yet, undocumented.
The solution works out of the box for whatever style of sectioning levels one chooses via `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[]{}`.

The first one creates a command that can be fed to the option `entrynumberformat`.
However, some styles do not recognize this option, f.i. `dottedtocline`. So

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[indent=0.5em,
entrynumberformat=\linkedentrynumber]
{dottedtocline}{chapter}
```

will not compile.

In this case, it helps to switch to the highly flexible style `tocline`, which can be easily customized so as to mimick the behavior of `dottedtocline`:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=0pt,
indent=0.5em,
linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
entrynumberformat=\linkedentrynumber]
{tocline}{chapter}
```

looks reasonably similar and works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ulrikes [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575191) you could use

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[linktoc=page,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\linkedentrynumber[1]{%
  \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
    #1
  \else
   \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}#1\hyper@linkend
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entrynumberformat=\linkedentrynumber
]{tocline}{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{Baz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use the undocumented (ie. they could change in the future) hooks `\numberline@numberprefix` and `\numberline@numberpostfix` provided by `tocbasic`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[linktoc=page,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro{\numberline@numberprefix}{%
    \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty\else\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}\fi
  }
  \g@addto@macro{\numberline@numberpostfix}{%
    \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty\else\hyper@linkend\fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{Baz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great.

I should mention that *solution 2* (the undocumented tocbasic hooks)
works out of the box and *for all `TOCStyleEntry`s*.

While *solution 1* uses the option `entrynumberformat`, so it will only work for an entry style that can take this option, such as `tocline` (as in your example).

In my real-life setup I used `dottedtocline` for some sectioning levels,
so solution 1 wouldn't compile.
But I can switch to the highly flexible `tocline` and mimick the behavior of `dottedtocline`.
(Sorry for not mentioning this in the MWE, I will edit my question accordingly.)